# How would I go about making popout divs?

Tags: html, popup

My page is called services and is going to be like a list of all the different services but instead of links I want them to be little graphics (I know how to do them ) and when they are clicked they open a box on top of the webpage, in the center, which displays two divs, an image on one side and text on the other?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want an overlay to display some content. The easiest way to do this is with one of the many third party JQuery solutions. Have a look at http://jquerytools.org/

They all have documentation and are easily fixed to your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery UI is a great tool (heavy though). 
Here is the page with demos and documentation you are probably looking for: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/